# Detecting when a program is closed in command prompt

Tags: batch-file

I have a code that allows me to change the system date when I launch a program. I want my code to change the date when I close said program.

```
set before=%date%
echo 01/06/2012 | date
start C:\Skittles\Rainbows3.1\angels.cmd
timeout 5
echo %before% | date
```

so instead of changing the date right away (lines 4-5 of my code), I want it to change when the program closes

hope this was clear enough.

Comment: Did you try `start /wait` ?

Comment: I did. Either I'm doing it wrong or it's not working.

Comment: In the code shown `start /wait` won't return until `angels.cmd` exits.  My guess is that `angels.cmd` is not actually the program you're interested in, but just a script that launches that program.  If so, you'll need to modify `angels.cmd` so that it doesn't exit until the program does, or launch the program directly instead of launching the script.

Comment: when i use start /wait, if i close the program i have to close the command prompt attached to it manually(created by start). After that, the original prompt asks me if it shoul be closed yes/no. if i choose no, the final date command runs. is there a way to make it do all that without asking for confirmation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, so I did some tests, and it turns out the behaviour of the `start` command when applied to a batch script is not what I thought it was.

It turns out that

```
start anyscript.cmd
```

leaves the new command window open (at the command prompt) when the script terminates.  Similarly,

```
start /wait anyscript.cmd
```

does not return until the new command window is explicitly closed.

The work-around is straightforward: use

```
start /wait cmd /c anyscript.cmd
```

This will exit when the script does.

You may also want to consider whether you really want the new command window.  Alternatives include

```
cmd /c anyscript.cmd
```

and

```
call anyscript.cmd
```

both of which will run the batch script in the existing command window.